# From webpack to brunch (config files)

Tags: javascript, webpack, brunch

I want to use `brunch` **instead** of `webpack`, but couldn't figure out how to create the config for it given my existing webpack config and folder structure.

This is my existing structure. With webpack I would get 4 entry chunks, `['app1', 'app2', 'app3', 'app4']` and a `commons.js` that extracts node_modules and dependencies used by multiple entry chunks.

```
src
+ js
  + app1
    + src
      - index.js
    + node_modules

  + app2
    + src
      - index.js
    + node_modules

  + app3
    + src
      - index.js
    + node_modules

  + app4
    + src
      - index.js
    + node_modules
```

How do I configure brunch to create a bundle for each `app`, but create something similar like `commons.js` using multiple dependency trees? All the example I found use the project skeleton for brunch...